# Transfer formula result from one tab to another on iCloud Numbers

Tags: icloud, numbers

On Numbers for iCloud, how do I transfer a formula result from one cell to another on a different tab, but in the same spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this to be sure it worked. Go to the cell you want to copy and choose "Edit > Copy" or Hold down the Command key **WHILE** pressing the C key. Switch to the tab and cell you want to paste into then choose "Edit > Paste Formula Results" or Hold down the Command key AND Shift key **WHILE** pressing the V key.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but the thing is that this way it doen't update the results...

Comment: what results? you need to clarify **EXACTLY** what is happening versus what you **want** to have happen.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to "Paste Formula Results" or "paste values" when using Numbers in iCloud via Safari,

BUT

"Paste and Match Style" pastes the values without the formula.